# Determining equivalent arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, set, duplicates, unique

In java, What is the most efficient way to decide whether two arrays contain all of the same elements. The arrays can have duplicates or can be unsorted. Most efficient meaning run time complexity and space complexity.

Comment: Wait, define equivalence. And why are there three arrays in your second example?

Comment: The most efficient as in fast? Or code-wise?

Comment: Wanted to find a way to do this myself rather than using a built in method. Thanks though.

Comment: Most efficient meaning run time complexity.

Comment: Equivalence means that every item in each array has to be in the other arrays, but the other array doesn't have to have the duplicates. It does not matter how many arrays are given as arguments, as long as you check all of them are equivalent.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch answered above

Comment: A simple optimisation is to first check all the sizes match.  Depending on your use case, this could pick up a lot of differences in O(N) time where N is the number of arrays.

Comment: Does the order matter? Is `[[1, 2], [3]]` equivalent to `[[3], [2, 1]]`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey The order does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMaps` too keep track of the values you have previously seen :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(allEquivalents(new String[][] { { "1", "3" }, { "1", "1", "3" } })); // true
    System.out.println(allEquivalents(new String[][] { { "1" }, { "1", "1", "1" }, { "1", "1", "2" } })); // false
}

public static boolean allEquivalents(String[][] arrays) {
    final HashMap<String, Integer> foundValues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        for (final String key : arrays[i]) {
            // we have a value not seen in the previous array, return false
            if (i > 0 && (!foundValues.containsKey(key) || foundValues.get(key) < i - 1)) {
                return false;
            }
            foundValues.put(key, i);
        }
    }
    // check if all the values where in the last array
    for (final Integer i : foundValues.values()) {
        if (i < arrays.length - 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You are iterating only once on each value, and once on the values in the `HashMap`. So, the complexity is `O(n)`, with `n` your total number of values.

Comment: Can you explain what that last check does?  Why don't you know if all the i values were less than array.length-1 in the first pair of loops?

Comment: @PeterLawrey In the case `[["2", "1"], ["1"]]`, if you don't do this check, you will miss the fact that `"2"` was only in the first array.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether order matters, you could be right.

Comment: @PeterLawrey From what I understood, duplicates and order doesn't matter, two arrays are equivalent as soon as they contain the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are willing to use some additional storage (such as `HashSet` as mentioned in the comments), you must sort the two arrays prior to finding out if they are equivalent. Then you can do one iteration on the two arrays, and verify that each value found in the first array is also found in the second array.

Sorting the arrays would take you O(n log n), where n is the size of the longer of the two arrays. Iterating over the sorted arrays would take O(n). Therefore the overall time complexity would be O(n log n).

Assuming the arrays are sorted, this is how you find if they are equivalent (hopefully I don't have any bugs, as I didn't test it):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int value = -1;
while (i<arr1.length && j<arr2.length) {
    int value = arr1[i];
    if (!value.equals(arr2[j]))
        return false;
    do {i++;} while (i<arr1.length && arr1[i].equals(value));
    do {j++;} while (j<arr2.length && arr2[j].equals(value));
}
while (i<arr1.length) {
    if (!arr1[i].equals(value))
        return false;
    i++;
}
while (j<arr2.length) {
    if (!arr2[j].equals(value))
        return false;
    j++;
}
return true;
```

Comment: with some added space complexity it could be done in O(n). Just add all elements of one array to a set, then see if all elements in the other array are in the set.

Comment: +1 You can also use HashSet and compare those.  The amortized time complexity is O(n) but there is a good chance this is slower for smaller arrays.

Comment: @keyser I assume you don't mean just any set e.g. not TreeSet or ConcurrentSkipListSet or CopyOnWriteArraySet.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No, I mean the concept. No duplicates. One with a fast contains method would of course be preferable.

Comment: @keyser for tree sets, adding is O(N log N), to get O(N) you need HashSet if you use builtin sets.

Comment: Why do we need to sort the array? Since order does not matter here, as long as all the arrays contain the same elements, but do not need to have the same no. of duplicates

Comment: @user37375 To compare two arrays which could be in any order the time complexity is O(N ^ 2), if you know they are in sorted order it's O(N) but you need to do an O(N log N) sort first.  You can compare to HashSets in O(N) with O(N) insert time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know this :p Also, how about a HashMap?

Comment: @keyser HashSet is built on HashMap unfortunately. You can say it behaves the same even though it should be slightly more efficient given it doesn't have a value to record (but it has a dummy value in it's HashMap)

Comment: Most efficient meaning run time complexity and space complexity.

Comment: @user37375 Both? Well, you'll get to choose which one to prioritize.

Comment: You are doing a type of merge sort, but this assumes each array is in sorted order.  This is over kill as you can just compare the same elements.  BTW you need to check for and "sort" nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is O(n) amortized time, for either solution and supports nested arrays inside array of any/varying levels. e.g. you can compare

```
[1, [2, [3, 4], [4, 5], [3, 4]]]
```

Note: [3, 4] is a duplicate.

To use a Hash collection you need to use HashSet is duplicates are ignored and HashMap if duplicates are not ignored.  Map is required as you might have duplicates in which case, you need to count them.

```
public static boolean unorderedEquivalence(Object[] arr1, Object[] arr2) {
    return asSet(arr1).equals(asSet(arr2));
}

// if you want to ignore duplicates
private static Set<Object> asSet(Object[] arr1) {
    Set<Object> ret = new HashSet<>();
    for (Object o : arr1) {
        if (o instanceof Object[])
            o = asSet((Object[]) o);
        ret.add(o);
    }
    return ret;
}

// if you want to count duplicates.
private static Map<Object, ? extends Number> asSet(Object[] arr1) {
    Map<Object, Integer> ret = new HashMap<>();
    for (Object o : arr1) {
        if (o instanceof Object[])
            o = asSet((Object[]) o);
        Integer count = ret.get(o);
            ret.put(o, count == null ? 1 : count+1);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I think you might have misunderstood the question. We are given an arrays of arrays, so we cannot have nested arrays. Also, we are allowed to have duplicates, so we do not need to keep count of it. We just need to ignore duplicates and ordering and check whether all elements in one array is also in the other arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the arrays are of the same size, **n** - if not, return false.
I can think of two approaches...

1. **Sort the arrays -> O(nlogn)**. Iterate through array a, comparing every element at a[i] to b[i], returning false if they aren't equal.
2. **Use Trie -> O(n.m)** , where m is just log of value of the largest integer in your arrays. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie . Steps: put all elements of array a into trie, when you put it there for the first time, you set value associated with the key to 1. The next time you are inserting same key, just increment the associated value that is already present. Then iterate through the second array, doing decrement() operation which is the same as add(), only you decrement this time. If you decrement value to 0, remove the element. If you can't find such key in the trie, return false. After successfully iterating second array, check if trie is empty. If it is empty, return true, otherwise false.
3. **Use auxiliary array -> O(n)**.

This approach applicable only if you know maximum value of the elements in the arrays:

```
boolean arrayEquality(int[] a, int[] b, int maxValue) {
  int[] aux = new int[maxValue];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int value = a[i];
    aux[value]++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    int value = b[i];
    aux[value]--;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
    if (aux[i] != 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Or you can use HashSets but you will need to implement your own custom HashSet which will not replace previous key.